# echo based on grep result

Tags: bash, scripting, grep

I need a one liner which displays 'yes' or 'no' whether grep finds any results.

I have played with `grep -c`, but without success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
uptime | grep user && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
uptime | grep foo && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
```

Then you can have it quiet:

```
uptime | grep --quiet user && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
uptime | grep --quiet foo && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
```

From the grep manual page:

> EXIT STATUS
>
> Normally, the exit status is 0 if selected lines are found and 1
>   otherwise.  But the exit status  is
>          2  if  an error occurred, unless the -q or --quiet or --silent
>   option is used and a selected line is
>          found.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "one liner", for me this is a "one liner"

Just add `; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; fi` after you grep command

```
bash$ grep ABCDEF /etc/resolv.conf; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; fi
No
bash$ grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; fi
nameserver 212.27.54.252
Yes
```

Add -q flag to grep if you want to supress grep result

```
bash$ grep -q nameserver /etc/resolv.conf; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; fi
Yes
```

Answer (score 2):

This version is intermediate between **[Weboide's](https://serverfault.com/questions/153012/echo-based-on-grep-result/153013#153013)** version and **[radius's](https://serverfault.com/questions/153012/echo-based-on-grep-result/153015#153015)** version:

```
if grep --quiet foo bar; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
```

It's more readable than the former and it doesn't unnecessarily use `$?` like the latter.